# polymodel.PolyModel put() overriding

Tags: python, google-app-engine

i need to override the put method on my model because i need to do some special stuff while storing the entity.

the code looks something like this:

```
class Asset(polymodel.PolyModel):
....

def put(self, rpc=None):
  # do something special
  return self


class Image(Asset):
...
```

now my problem is that if i call Asset.put() it calls the custom put method while Image.put() uses the default one. If Asset would be a db.Model this works as expected Image.put() would use the custom put().

how can i make the subclass use the custom function?
thx

Comment: The image instance should use the custom put() with your code

Comment: but it does not. i put a logging into the put and it gets called only on Asset. it sounds weird to me too.

Comment: you should add part of your code

Comment: just found out that my code wasn't using the custom put() because of an wrong indentation. now it works as expected. thx

Answer (score 2):

While it is possible to monkey-patch your classes to allow you to change the behavior of put(), you might be better off writing a method -- call it save() for the sake of argument -- that wraps the put() in a more explicit and obvious fashion and frees you from having to worry about having the patched behaviors being inherited or not by subclasses.

Comment: Depending on what you're using the put() override for you might also be able to get the desired behavior by using a DerivedProperty from AETycoon: https://github.com/Arachnid/aetycoon/blob/master/__init__.py